# validar un formulario con JS

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy intentando validar este formulario y me da error la función.
También quiero bloquear los inputs que están dentro de ruta y al clickar en "BBB" que se desbloqueen y no hay forma.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre">
    <input type="email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    <input type="phone" placeholder="+00 000000000" name="telefono">
    <input type="radio" name="aaa" id="aaa" value="aaa">
    <label>AAA</label>
    <input type="radio" name="bbb" id="bbb" value="bbb">
    <label>BBB</label>
        <div id="ruta">
            <input type="checkbox" name="opcion1" id="opcion1" value="opcion1">
            <label>OPCIÓN 1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="opcion2" id="opcion2" value="opcion2">
            <label>OPCIÓN 2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="opcion3" id="opcion3" value="opcion3">
            <label>OPCIÓN 3</label>
        </div>
    <textarea placeholder="Escribe aquí tu mensaje:" name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" name="aceptar" id="aceptar" value="1">
    <label>Acepto la política de privacidad</label>
    <button type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="validar()">Enviar</button>
</form>

<script>
    $("#ruta").disabled="true";

     function enabled(){
        $("#ruta").disabled="false";
     }

     function validar(){

     }
</script>
```

¡¡¡Muchas gracias de antemano!!!
Y si también me ayudáis con PHP os lo agradecería mucho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de nada te recomendaría que dieras un vistazo a los selectores jQuery ya que te pueden ayudar con las cosas que planteas: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Para lo que quieres hacer te recomendaría cambiar el HTML de las opciones a:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="opcion1" id="opcion1" value="opcion1" disabled>
```

Esto es mejor así ya que por defecto estarán deshabilitadas.

Después puedes capturar el evento click en el input bbb

```
$("input[name='bbb']").click(funtction() { 
    $("input[name^='opcion'}").prop( "disabled", false );
});
```

Para capturar el evento de envío del formulario y validar puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
$( "#form1" ).submit(function( event ) {
  ...tu código de validación...
  event.preventDefault();
});
```